# When using the .join function in Python with a list, how do I prevent the first character from being the variable I am joining with?

Tags: python

```py
def convert_table(filename_in, filename_out):
  retlist = []
  with open(filename_in, 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:
      split = line.split(";")
      for i in split:
        i = i.replace(",",";")
        retlist.append(i)
    s = ","
    s = s.join(retlist)
    print(s)
    with open(filename_out,'w') as fdnew:
      fdnew.write(s)
  return True
```

So when I write this output to another file, all the new lines will start with a "," such that two lines of the output are

```
,String,Categorical,Categorical,Int,Int,Int,Int,Float,Float,Int,Int,Int,Int,Float,Float,Float
,100% Bran,N,C,70,4,1,130,10,5,6,280,25,3,1,0.33,68.402973
```

How do I get rid of the comma before the word String and before the 100%?

Answer (score 3):

You're reading data from the file, and putting *all* the data into *one* giant, flat list. The data you read includes line break characters, so if the file looks like

```
1;2;3
a;b;c
```

then the list you build looks like

```
['1', '2', '3\n', 'a', 'b', 'c\n']
```

and `s.join(retlist)` results in `'1,2,3\n,a,b,c\n'`, with a comma after the line break.

---

Instead of building one giant list, building one list per line and writing one line at a time would be one way to solve your problem.

Also, it looks like you want to turn all semicolons into commas and vice versa. There's an easier way to do that than this split/replace/join stuff. Strings have a `translate` method to replace characters with other characters:

```
converted = s.translate(str.maketrans({',': ';', ';': ','}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the first element of `retlist` is an empty string?  The behavior of join doesn't start with the joining value, but if the first element is an empty string it would appear that way.  For example

```
In [1]: l = ["", "hello", "world"]

In [2]: ','.join(l)
Out[2]: ',hello,world'
```

If this is the case (and an empty string doesn't provide any value to you), you could remove those from `retlist` before you do the `join`.  This could be done w/ something like

```
l = [e for e in l if e != '']
```